# Best way to code a QBE Restful method?

Tags: java, rest, seam, resteasy

I'm working on developing some web services using RESTeasy and Seam.  One of the services I'd like to create is a Query by Example service.

I first tried to code it like this:

```
@GET
@Produces("application/xml")
@Consumes("application/xml")
@Path("/matching")
public MessageList getMatchingMessages(Message msg);
```

This, unfortunately, produced complications in the client:

```
[testng] [Parser] Running:
[testng]   C:\Users\bdw\workspace-shepherd\GPRI\test-build\testng-Test.xml
[testng] java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod cannot be cast to org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod
[testng]    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:104)
[testng]    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:59)
[testng]    at $Proxy138.getMatchingMessages(Unknown Source)
```

and so on.  A variation of this method allows for a date range but, obviously, doesn't work in this form either:

```
@GET
@Produces("application/xml")
@Consumes("application/xml")
@Path("/matching")
public MessageList getMatchingMessages(@QueryParam("startDate") Date start,
        @QueryParam("endDate") Date end, Message msg);
```

When I got to thinking about it, passing a Message to a GET method might violate the spirit of REST.  Certainly, removing the Consumes annotation from the method allows the client to run without these errors.  But it begs the question, what *is* the right way to write a query method that takes non-URL-based, XML input and produces XML output?  Or that takes both XML and url-based parameters and produces XML output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you think you may want to cache the results?  If the answer is no, then you can simply use POST instead.

```
POST /QueryEngine
Content-Type: application/xml

=>
200 OK
Content-Type: application/xml
```

If the answer is maybe you might want to cache the results then you could do:

```
POST /QueryGenerator
Content-Type: application/xml

=>
303 See Other
Location: /GeneratedQuery/2323

GET /GeneratedQuery/2323
```

Having said all of this, are you sure you can't just use query parameters instead of passing XML?

Comment: The messages have upwards of 50 attributes and come in 25 flavors, so I was hoping to stick to the QBE except where a particular query is so frequent as to warrant parameterizing it.  That said, the POST idea, I think, fits the need and the spirit of REST, so that's what I'm going to try next.

Answer (score 2):

I can't help with the coding side of your question, but if you're passing in a non-URL input, then the POST method would be more appropriate than GET. You are in effect creating a new resource: a list of messages that match the example.

Comment: I like that way of thinking of the problem.  Sounds like POST is the way to go.  Thanks!